# Limit of a Function with Parameter

Tags: limits, functions

Given that $a\ne-1, \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = L$, prove **by limit definition** ($\epsilon, \delta)$  that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(\frac{a+1}{2x}) = L$.

I would greatly appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

Edit: I corrected the statement, I apologize for the inaccuracy.

Comment: What has to do the limit to prove with $f$?

Comment: Please correct your statement, there is some mistake. Is it really $2x$ or $f(x)$ in the denominator?

Comment: As it is right now, the limit is ${a + 1 \over 2 \infty} = 0$. Clearly not what you claim. Unless you correct it, we cannot give you any answer.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I'll correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=L$, we may choose $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Choose $M>0$ so that $\frac{|a+1|}{2M}<\delta$. Then for $x>M$, $$\frac{|a+1|}{2x}<\frac{|a+1|}{2M}<\delta,$$ so that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$. Hence, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f\left(\frac{a+1}{2x}\right)=L$.

Comment: Thank you! When choosing the M shouldn't it be the absolute value that is smaller than $\delta$?

Comment: If you're considering $x\to\infty$, then $x$ is positive anyway.

Comment: Yea that's true. But I think the choice of $a$ can make the argument positive or negative, no?

Comment: Fair enough. I added the absolute values.